# Print UTF-16 string

Tags: c, utf-16

So I want to parse IDv3.4 file. There are 4 types of text encoding in format specification: `ISO-8859-1`, `UTF-16 with BOM`, `UTF-16BE` and `UTF-8`. I already written code that can obtains bytes of strings.

And my question is how to print `UTF-16 with BOM` and `UTF-16BE` bytes to console.

And also one important condition: I can use only C libraries. I can't use C++ libraries. I even can't use third-party C libraries.

Comment: It's possible that your terminal window doesn't support this, no matter what your code does. Some characters are just hard to display properly in a monospace, half-width font.

Comment: But I can't check it because I just don't know function that can print utf-16 string. I assumed that wprintf can do it but it can't.

Comment: Try `putwchar`.

Comment: Depends on what your terminal supports -- convert the UTF-16 to something it supports and print that.  Since you don't seem to have trouble with UTF-8, then perhaps your terminal supports that (Linux, for example).  So just convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 and print that,

Comment: The question is not clear because *parsing* the ID3v2 tag does not require interpreting the text at all.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the text from it? Print it to a terminal? Display it in a GUI element? Convert it to some particular form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general (NOT specifically for parsing IDv3.4 files alone) you will want to choose a common character encoding that your code will use internally; then convert from any other character encoding into your chosen character encoding (for input data - e.g. from user or files or network) and convert back again (for output, to user or files or network).

For choosing a common character encoding:

- you want something that minimizes "nonconvertible cases" - e.g. you wouldn't want to choose ASCII because there's far too much in far too many other character encodings that can't be converted to ASCII. This mostly means that you'll want a Unicode encoding.
- you want something that is convenient. For Unicode encoding, this only really gives you 2 choices - UTF-8 (because you don't have to care about endian issues, and it's relatively efficient for space/memory consumption, and C functions like `strlen()` can still work) and versions of UTF-32 (because each codepoint takes up a fixed amount of space and it makes conversion a little simpler). Of these, the benefits of UTF-32 are mostly unimportant (unless you're doing a font rendering engine).
- the "whatever random who-knows-what" character encoding that the C compiler uses is irrelevant (for both `char` and `w_char`), because it's implementation specific and not portable.
- the "whatever random who-knows-what" character encoding that the terminal uses is irrelevant (the terminal should be considered "just another flavor of input/output, where conversion is involved").

Assuming you choose UTF-8:

- You might be able to force the compiler to treat string literals as UTF-8 for you (e.g. like `u8"hello"` in C++, except I can't seem to find any sane standard for C). Otherwise you'll need to do it yourself where necessary.
- I'd recommend using the `uint8_t` type for storing strings; partly because `char` is "signed or unsigned, depending on which way the wind is blowing" (which makes conversions to/from other character encodings painful due to "shifting a signed/negative number right" problems), and partly because it help to find "accidentally used something that isn't UTF-8" bugs (e.g. warnings from compiler about "conversion from signed to unsigned").
- Conversion between UTF-8 and UTF-32LE, UTF_32BE, UTF-16LE, UTF_16BE is fairly trivial (the relevant wikipedia articles are enough to describe how it works).
- "UTF-16 with BOM" means that the first 2 bytes will tell you if it's UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE, so (after you add support for UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE) it's trivial. "UTF-32 with BOM" is similar (first 4 bytes tell you if it's UTF32-BE or UTF32-BE).
- Conversion to/from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 is fairly trivial, because the characters match Unicode codepoints with the same value. However, often people get it wrong (e.g. say it's ISO-8859-1 when the data is actually encoded as Windows-1252 instead); and for the conversion from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 you will need to deal with "nonconvertible" codepoints.